# Get ip address from if equal to description

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that checks all ip addresses in DHCP scope, and gives me only the addresses that have a certain description, can anyone help me out with this.

Current code:

```
get-dhcpserverv4reservation | select -clientid - description
```

Comment: Of course we can! What have you tried so far? Share your attempts and we can help you find the right answer. Remember that StackOverflow is not a code-writing service!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have tried &#39;get-dhcpserverv4reservation | select  -clientid - description&#39; but I can&#39;t seem to figure out how to get only the address that equal to the description

I really need to get the address that the Mac address start with 0021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation |
    Select-Object ClientID, Description |
    Where-Object Description -eq "this description, here"
```

Comment: I'll give that a go